# What is the best way to look for ELF Shared Libraries under linux in C

Tags: linux, elf

I am currently working on a userland ELF File loader in C. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` does not seem to be an option for me, as it does not seem to be set by default on my system(x86_64 openSUSE). What is the best way to get all of the directories where libraries are stored ?

Comment: `man ldconfig` has all the answers you need

Comment: Why do you need a userland ELF file loader? Your question is too short and lacks motivation & context. Please **edit your question** to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/lib64` and `/lib64` for 64-bit binaries or `/usr/lib` and `/lib` for 32-bit binaries, than paths taken from `/etc/ld.so.conf` and included configs

From `man ldconfig`

> `ldconfig` creates  the  necessary  links and cache to the most recent shared libraries found in the directories specified on the command line, in the  file  `/etc/ld.so.conf`, and  in  the trusted directories, `/lib` and `/usr/lib` (on some 64-bit architectures such as x86-64, `/lib` and `/usr/lib` are the trusted directories for  32-bit  libraries,  while `/lib64` and `/usr/lib64` are used for 64-bit libraries).
>
> The  cache  is used by the run-time linker, ld.so or ld-linux.so.

...

> /etc/ld.so.conf     File containing a list of directories, one per line, in  which to search for libraries.

Note that this info is for openSUSE, other distros may use different paths.

Comment: Other distributions can use different directories to store shared libraries, but the mechanism is the same... those directories are listed in `/etc/ld.so.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is the standard environment variable used for users to add and load their own libraries when they are unable or have no access to the system directories to install shared libraries.

There's a file which is normally read by `ldconfig` at boot time (it reads `/etc/ld.so.conf` to create a binary DBMsomewhat file `/etc/ld.so.cache`, with a hash table to quick access the paths to use when loading library shared objects, and that is used by the dynamic loader (there's only one such thing, as a kernel tool, so it is not dependant on which distribution you run, but just on the kernel version you use  ---it has changed somewhat, but not as much as the kernel does---)

To know which sonames (**soname** is the common name used by a shared object to refer to an interface, which is what is required to warranty that a shared object will be compatible with the library) are being used by the dynamic loader, just run

```
ldconfig -p
```

and you'll get all the sonames registered, and the path to the library actually loaded for that soname.

If you want to know which libraries will be loaded by some specific executable by the dynamic loader, just execute this:

```
ldd your_executable
```

and It will print the sonames that executable needs and where in the system they are located.

What `ldconfig(8)` does, is to search al the directories included in the file `/etc/ld.so.conf` for shared object files, and look all the ones whose name matches the soname stored in the file, and include a reference to the file named for the soname found.  Once the table is completed, the file `/etc/ld.so.cache` is created and used by `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` which is the shared module in charge of user mode loading the rest of shared libraries used by a program.

There's no problem in having a local `$HOME/lib` directory to store your locally developed shared libraries, but as that directory will not be normally included in `/etc/ld.so.conf`, you'll need to create `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${HOME}/lib` and be careful **to export it**, and **never try to use it as root user**, as for root user that env variable is disabled.

## EDIT 1

By the way, if you need to load on demand a shared library  (this is possibly what you need, probably), read about `dlopen(3)` and friend functions, as that is the method used by most programs to dynamically load modules you haven't heard about before compilation of main program.  You'll need to load the module, look for the symbols you need (`dlsym(3)` or `dlfunc(3)`) store the references given by the module, and finally call them.